# I need create a button in java class and replace it in xml

Tags: android

I need create a button in java class and replace it in xml in a specific position like i want to put them in horizontal scrollView that i created in xml please any help + i need a function the allow me to generate button automatically according to my array size thanks. .

Comment: Please post your code you are having issues with, don't ask others to write it for you.

Comment: Your right iam must do that but i did not know from the beginning how to  post it i'm new user but thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout); 
LayoutParams layoutParam_text=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); layoutParam_text.gravity=Gravity.LEFT; 
Button btnTest[]=new Button[array.size];

    for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++)
    {
        btnTest[i] =new Button(this);
        btnTest[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParam_text);
        btnTest[i].setTag(""+i);
        btnTest[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

            }
        });
        layout.addView(btnTest[i]);
    }
```